# Импорт telegraf в модуле nestjs

Tags: telegram-bot, typescript, nestjs

Создал простой модуль (telegram-bot) в приложении nestjs

src\telegram-bot\telegram-bot.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TelegramBotService } from './telegram-bot.service';

@Module({
  providers: [TelegramBotService],
})
export class TelegramBotModule {}
```

src\telegram-bot\telegram-bot.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, OnApplicationBootstrap } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Telegraf } from 'telegraf';
import config from 'config';

interface TelegramConfig {
  token: string
}

const TELEGRAM_CONFIG: TelegramConfig = config.get('telegram');

@Injectable()
export class TelegramBotService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  private bot: Telegraf;

  onApplicationBootstrap(): void {
    const { token } = TELEGRAM_CONFIG;
    this.bot = new Telegraf(token);
    this.bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Hello'));
    this.bot.launch();
  }
}
```

При компиляции проекта получаю ошибки в консоли:

```
node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:30:25 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

30     [P in tt.UpdateType as SnakeToCamelCase<P>]: PropOr<U, P, undefined>;
                           ~~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:30:28 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

30     [P in tt.UpdateType as SnakeToCamelCase<P>]: PropOr<U, P, undefined>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:30:47 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

30     [P in tt.UpdateType as SnakeToCamelCase<P>]: PropOr<U, P, undefined>;
                                                 ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:30:48 - error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

30     [P in tt.UpdateType as SnakeToCamelCase<P>]: PropOr<U, P, undefined>;
                                                  ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:30:73 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

30     [P in tt.UpdateType as SnakeToCamelCase<P>]: PropOr<U, P, undefined>;
                                                                           ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:31:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

31 } & {
   ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:31:3 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

31 } & {
     ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:32:14 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32     update: U;
                ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:33:31 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

33     updateType: UpdateTypes<U>;
                                 ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:34:41 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

34     senderChat: Getter<U, 'sender_chat'>;
                                           ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:35:28 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

35     from: Getter<U, 'from'>;
                              ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/composer.d.ts:36:28 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

36     chat: Getter<U, 'chat'>;
                              ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:68 - error TS1110: Type expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                     ~~~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:77 - error TS1005: '}' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                              ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:78 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                               ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:81 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                  ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:88 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                         ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:95 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:96 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                 ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:100 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                     ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:132 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                                                     ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:138 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                                                           ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:1:139 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1 export declare type SnakeToCamelCase<S extends string> = S extends `${infer T}_${infer U}` ? `${T}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamelCase<U>>}` : `${S}`;
                                                                                                                                            ~

node_modules/telegraf/typings/core/helpers/string.d.ts:2:37 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.

2 //# sourceMappingURL=string.d.ts.map
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой!

P.S.
В другом приложении на typescript (без использования какого-либо фреймворка) все компилируется и запускается нормально, как и должно быть.
Не знаю в чем проблема, в nest? Или у меня в проекте? Судя по гуглению ни у кого подобной проблемы не возникало (ну или никто не описывал её в инете)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалось в версии typescript. У меня в проекте стояла версия 4.0.5, когда обновился до 4.2.3 все скомпилировалось без ошибок. Версия telegraf 4.2.1